# Implement anti-aliasing filter in android

Tags: android, audio, filter

[image]According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/9Tt6XeUwJlA) it is not possible to implement an anti aliasing filter... is that right?
Any ideas or algorithms  on how the anti aliasing filter works?

I'm working with 17/18 KHz signals at a 44.1 sampling rate, it respects Shannon theorem, but still m getting the aliasing effect.

Comment: You're going to need to explain with more depth what you are doing and the signal path involved.  What is certainly true, is that if you have aliasing at the point you sample, it's game over. Beyond that point, low pass filters are regularly used when up or down-sampling to eliminate image signals.

Comment: im using a chirp signal generated from a phone's speaker. I could not understand what do you mean by 'What is certainly true, is that if you have aliasing at the point you sample, it's game over'..

Comment: It is not possible to separate the image (alias) from the signal you wanted after sampling. For this reason, before sampling takes place it  is important to ensure that the signal does not containing any components above the nyquist frequency.

Comment: i did make sure it verifies that. i'll show you the output of the chirp signal if you don't mind. as you can see at the end the frequency decreases and starts again..

Comment: First Off, it's not clear what your graph shows, I was expecting to see a graph of frequency vs Amplitude not frequency vs Time.

Comment: It's impossible for you to get Aliasing if you sampled at a frequency equal or higher than double the max frequency in your audio signal (16Khz).Please provide a frequency domain plot of your sampled signal.